# SQL Server: calculate sum of count and order by this

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, count, group-by

I want to create a basic ranking and sort the results of a stored procedure from the most appearing presenter to the lowest.

I tried the below which works fine if I remove the groupCount and the GROUP BY but I can't get it to include this so that it groups by the presenters. 
Basically what I want is to see the person who presented most (i.e. max of groupCount) on top and then the lower ranks up to the person who presented least (i.e. min of groupCount).

The error I am getting is the following:

```
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Procedure CountPresenters, Line 17
Column 'MeetingDetails.topic' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

My stored procedure so far:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CountPresenters]
    @title nvarchar(200)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT      B.presenter,
                B.topic,
                A.meetingDate,
                A.title,
                COUNT(*) AS groupCount
    FROM        MeetingDetails B
    INNER JOIN  MeetingDates A
    ON          B.meetingID = A.meetingID
    WHERE       B.itemStatus = 'active'
    AND         A.title LIKE '%'+@title+'%'
    GROUP BY    B.presenter
    ORDER BY    groupCount desc, B.presenter, A.meetingDate desc
    FOR XML PATH('presenters'), ELEMENTS, TYPE, ROOT('ranks')
END
```

Many thanks for any help with this, Tim.

Comment: Nothing to do with joining, if you aggregate a column, all columns must also either be aggregated or grouped by.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this resolved by using temp tables. Thanks anyways !

Answer (score 1):

Whatever field you took into select statement that must be included  while you'r using group by function. Here is modified query. Hope it would be worked.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CountPresenters]
    @title nvarchar(200)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT      B.presenter,
                B.topic,
                A.meetingDate,
                A.title,
                COUNT(*) AS groupCount
    FROM        MeetingDetails B
    INNER JOIN  MeetingDates A
    ON          B.meetingID = A.meetingID
    WHERE       B.itemStatus = 'active'
    AND         A.title LIKE '%'+@title+'%'
    GROUP BY    B.presenter,
                B.topic,
                A.meetingDate,
                A.title
    ORDER BY    groupCount desc, B.presenter, A.meetingDate desc
    FOR XML PATH('presenters'), ELEMENTS, TYPE, ROOT('ranks')
```

Comment: Thanks for this ! Here I don't get the error which is good but it still doesnt group and order as I want. It should group by the presenters and order from highest groupCount to lowest (the rest is less important).

Comment: Add: It looks like the problem is that it doesnt add the count for the presenters as it always starts again with 1 even if a presenter appears more than once.

Comment: you want to display all below fields ?B.presenter,
                B.topic,
                A.meetingDate,
                A.title,

Comment: Yes but I want to count by presenter and then group and order by this.

Comment: Was your last comment deleted ?

Comment: Yes but here it's again. see you'r getting result as per your expectation or not. ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CountPresenters]
    @title nvarchar(200)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT      B.presenter,
                COUNT(*) AS groupCount
    FROM        MeetingDetails B
    INNER JOIN  MeetingDates A
    ON          B.meetingID = A.meetingID
    WHERE       B.itemStatus = 'active'
    AND         A.title LIKE '%'+@title+'%'
    GROUP BY    B.presenter
    ORDER BY    groupCount desc, B.presenter, A.meetingDate desc
    FOR XML PATH('presenters'), ELEMENTS, TYPE, ROOT('ranks')
END

Comment: But I think that it was due to inner join because inner join means if meeting id exists in both the table then only it would be displayed result. if you want to show all data of first table then you need to make left outer join rather than inner join.

Comment: Thanks - This does not include the other items like topic and meetingDate anymore.

Answer (score 1):

In group by clause you have to add topic, meetingDate and title along with presenter

Corrected query:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CountPresenters]
    @title nvarchar(200)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT      B.presenter,
                B.topic,
                A.meetingDate,
                A.title,
                COUNT(*) AS groupCount
    FROM        MeetingDetails B
    INNER JOIN  MeetingDates A
    ON          B.meetingID = A.meetingID
    WHERE       B.itemStatus = 'active'
    AND         A.title LIKE '%'+@title+'%'
    GROUP BY    B.presenter,  B.topic,
                A.meetingDate,
                A.title
    ORDER BY    groupCount desc, B.presenter, A.meetingDate desc
    FOR XML PATH('presenters'), ELEMENTS, TYPE, ROOT('ranks')
END
```

Comment: Thanks. This is the same as the above. It works but it doesnt group by the groupCount so that it counts each record separately even if a presenter appears more than once.

Comment: It looks like it just doesnt add up the single counts for the same presenters.